# GDB not reacting Ctrl-C when after fork() and setsid()

Tags: gdb

I'm debugging a daemon and after it forks and child calls setsid() the execution cannot be interrupted by pressing Ctrl-C.

Here is a simple example:

```
// test.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    if(fork())
    {
        printf("Parent\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Child\n");
    setsid();
    for(;;)
            i++;
    return 0;
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. gcc -g -o test test.c
2. gdb ./test
3. In gdb shell:

   - `set follow-fork-mode child` (because by default gdb follows parent process)
   - `run`
   - press Ctrl-C

And nothing happens. Even if I send SIGINT to the process, it is hanging.  I have to kill gdb to stop this.

But I can interrupt loop if I send SIGINT **before** pressing Ctrl-C. If I set breakpoint inside loop, process stops on it fine.

If I comment out one of "fork()" or "setsid()", everything works as expected.

Some workarounds I know are:

- Run process in foreground for debugging purpose
- Add some sleep in child process after it daemonizes. And attach gdb to it

But maybe someone knows better solution or can explain, why this is happening.

Thanks in advance

```
Linux 4.12.10-1 x86_64
gcc 7.1.1
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0
```

UPD 2017-09-11:

Some more research (here `stat <process>` stands for `grep State /proc/<pid of process>/status`)

Scenario 1 (send SIGINT **before** pressing Ctrl-C, in this case everything work as expected)

```
$ stat gdb
State:  S (sleeping)
$ stat test
State:  R (running)
$ killall -SIGINT test
$ stat gdb
State:  S (sleeping)
$ stat test
State:  t (tracing stop)
```

Scenario 2 (send SIGINT **after** pressing Ctrl-C, in this case gdb seems to be hanging)

```
$ stat gdb
State:  R (running)
$ stat test
State:  R (running)
$ killall -SIGINT test
$ stat gdb
State:  R (running)
$ stat test
State:  t (tracing stop)

$ grep TracerPid /proc/`pidof test`/status
TracerPid:      26533
```

Backtrace of gdb:

```
#0  0x00007fbf7bb316c0 in __write_nocancel () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00005625e2cc090c in serial_event_set(serial_event*) ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007fbf7aae3ba7 in kill () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00005625e2cf908b in default_target_pass_ctrlc(target_ops*) ()
#5  0x00005625e2d0b3a4 in maybe_quit() ()
#6  0x00005625e2c24e92 in invoke_async_signal_handlers() ()
#7  0x00005625e2c259e6 in start_event_loop() ()
#8  0x00005625e2c7d33b in captured_command_loop(void*) ()
#9  0x00005625e2c27c55 in catch_errors(int (*)(void*), void*, char const*, return_mask) ()
#10 0x00005625e2c7e63f in gdb_main(captured_main_args*) ()
#11 0x00005625e2a62bec in main ()
```

Comment: After you send SIGINT to the child, what is the output of `grep State /proc/childpid/status` and `grep State /proc/gdbprocess/status` ? Does `grep TracerPid /proc/childpid/status` show the gdb process as the tracer?

Comment: Can you run gdb on the nonresponsive gdb and get a stack trace?

Comment: @mark-plotnick sorry, didn't notice your comment. Updated my post, stil don't understand what's happening